# AngularJS, easy way to show a delete button when a checkbox is checked in the list of users under ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I am trying to toggle a delete button which has already a function bound to it. The list is created with ng-repeat checking the users object. But the methds I have seen so far are either simple model show which does not work in my case. Or complex directive controller methods.

All I need is to check whether at least one checkbox is checked. Here is the snippet from the code:

```
                    <table class="table">
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in ctrl.commonUserService.users | filter:ctrl.commonUserService.suppressLoggedOnUserFilter()">

                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected" value="y" /></td>
                        <td title="User Name"><strong>{{user.userName}}</strong></td>
```

How can I easily do this with Angular? I tried to create a function looping users and looking if they are selected at all but don't think I can put this function to ng-show.

Comment: I tried something like this in controller.


`self.userChecked = function(){
  for (var i = commonUserService.users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(commonUserService.users[i].selected) {
       return true;
      }
  }

 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check if at least one box is selected when the state changes:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.selected" ng-change="ctrl.userSelected()" value="y" /></td> <!-- use ng-change to notify when a checkbox is clicked -->

<button ng-click="ctrl.delete()" ng-show="ctrl.usersSelected">Delete</button> <!-- if ctrl.usersSelected is true show delete -->
```

In the controller:

```
this.userSelected = function userSelected() { // when checkbox is clicked check users to see if at least one is selected and save the state in this.userSelected
    this.usersSelected = this.commonUserService.users.some(function(user) {
        return user.selected;
    });
};
```

Comment: is that 'some' a predefined method or is it a placeholder since you were not sure. I haven't been able to run this, but it may be because of scope and control names. but the way in module var self =this so I am changing all this instances to self here.

Comment: [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is an ES5 array method :)

Comment: cool great, thx. but somehow my button is still not showing. this is probably too advanced for me. user.selected is boolean but I was told that it should actually have an index. So is this returning boolean value?

Comment: It is actually working yes, thanks. I was confused with very similar names :) so had forgotten an 's'.

Comment: but what is the difference of writing this as below:
`this.userSelected = function () { 
    this.usersSelected = this.commonUserService.users.some(function(user) {
        return user.selected;
    });
};`

Comment: If you refer to `function userSelected` as the difference - the answer is none in functionality. Naming an anonymous function is for debugging purposes, as the console displays the name of the function, when there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily using the `ng-change` directive on your inputs. See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tLcrkwIMkv2lPgV4xjGX?p=preview) for the working example, but it basically goes like this:

**View:**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="isSelected()" ng-model="user.selected" /></td>
    <td title="User Name"><strong>{{user.userName}}</strong></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="delete" ng-show="showDelete">Delete</button>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.isSelected = function() {
    var somethingSelected = false;
    $scope.users.forEach(function(user, index) {
        if (user.selected) somethingSelected = true;
    });
    $scope.showDelete = somethingSelected;
};
```

Comment: Nvm, Ori beat me to it, and actually a bit simpler too, looks like.

Comment: Thanks I will try both. I am pretty new to AngularJS